# JSON parsed within Appdelegate

Tags: json, swift, xcode8, appdelegate

I'm developing an App Web Radio for church using Xcode8 Swift 3. I am in doubt as to what I should really call one storyboard or another.

Depending on the "status" in the JSON file at (http://tabernaculodafe.org.br/server.php) it should call the #webradio screen or the "alive" screen. I was able to define in the AppDelegate which storyboard should be "initial", but I could not get the JSON code to work on AppDelegate.

```
Type (If (status == 1) {screen webradio} else {screen live}
```

I do not know if it is the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think AppDelegate is not good place to perform such logics, it can lead to some problems. For example if there is no internet access than which view controller will be root view controller? 
Instead of AppDelegate you can create another view controller (let's say temporary launch screen) and implement server request in viewDidLoad method, and depending on the results show the appropriate view controller.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You welcome!!!!